# At what point is the prototype Object born in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, object, prototype-programming

Let's say I have a constructor function:

```
function Cat()
{
  this.tail = "long";
  this.colour = "black";
}

console.log(Cat.prototype); 
// returns an empty [object Object] with no properties (checked with `for...in` loop).
```

So it seems at this point `Cat.prototype` doesn't have`tail` and `colour`.

```
var Charlie = new Cat();
console.log(Charlie.tail);
```

So how does `Charlie` inherit the properties of `Cat` if they are not defined in its prototype. I was under the assumption that the whole point of the prototype object is to mirror or store the properties of the constructor that will be inherited by all instances of `cat`- is this wrong?

At what point does the prototype Object get filled up with these properties? Or does this happen only when I explicitly set `Cat.prototype.eyes = brown` as an example?

Moreover, what is the correct approach for querying the properties of an Object's prototype? Is it a `for...in` loop? I guess it can't be `Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Cat.prototype)` because that would not return inherited properties.

Comment: You usually want to put methods (functions) on the prototype, not string properties...

Comment: Yes, you can do `Object.getOwnPropertyNames( Cat.prototype )`, there's nothing wrong with that.

Answer (score 2):

You are defining the `tail` and `colour` properties directly on the instance. Those properties are not defined on the `prototype` object.

Btw, every function has a `prototype` property and it is created at the time when the function itself is created.

Answer (score 1):

`prototype` is completely seperate from `this`.

All the things in `this` will not get inherited, the things in `prototype` will.
By default you inherit from `Object.prototype` (which is empty)

```
function Cat()
{
  this.tail = "long";
  this.colour = "black";
}
Cat.prototype.getColour = function () {
  return this.colour;
}

WhiteCat.prototype = Cat.prototype;
WhiteCat.prototype.constructor = WhiteCat;

function WhiteCat(name){
  Cat.call(this);
  this.colour = "white";
}    

var c = new Cat();
console.log(c.getColour()); // "black"
var w = new WhiteCat();
console.log(w.getColour()); // "white"
```

Comment: That's not right - the `this` value represents the `Cat` instance and it does not have a `prototype` property. Only functions (like `Cat` in this case) have `prototype` properties.

Comment: Ah, right. Fixed it. I find prototypes to be extremely cumbersome. I recommend you use some framework to do inheritance for you if you're keen on sticking to OO.

Comment: It's not that bad, you get used to it. However, I'm not sure that `WhiteCat.prototype = Cat.prototype;` is a good idea. You usually want to have separate prototypes, so that you can define methods that are specific to one of the "classes" (`WhiteCat` in this case).

Answer (score 1):

Prototypes in Javascript are a little different than what you are describing. In this case `Charlie` does have a tail because `Charie` IS A `Cat` that is, he is an instance of `Cat` the Cat class. In your `Cat` function you add the tail property to all cats with the `this.tail =` line. This happens entirely because you called the function `Cat` with the `new` keyword. When you do that, javascript creates a new object and then makes `this` point to that object in the context of the function.

Now prototypes work differently, they are best thought of as a chain that will be followed if a you go looking for a property or function that is not present in an object. For example, if try to go:

```
Charlie.tickle_wiskers();
```

Javascript will go looking for a function called `tickle_wiskers` in the charlie object. If it does not find that function it will look in Charlies prototype (which by default is `Object.prototype` if you don't set it explicitly). Finally I could give all Cats that function by going like this:

```
Cat.prototype.tickle_wiskers = function() { 
      alert('meow');
    }
```

Comment: Consider not overwriting `Cat.prototype` with an object literal. That destroys the `Cat.prototype.constructor === Cat` relation. It's a better approach to add methods via `Cat.prototype.tickle = ...`

Answer (score 0):

The prototype will never get the properties that you put in the object. The object has the members of the prototype, but the prototype doesn't have the members of the object.

The object doesn't inherit anything from the prototype, the members in the prototype still only exists in the prototype, they are only accessible from the object. If you remove something from the protype after an object is created, that member is no longer accessible from the object either.

A function has a `prototype` property, and when you use the `new` keyword to call the function as a constructor, the object that is created gets the prototype from the function.

If you add something to the prototype of a function, it will also be accessible by objects that were created using the function, even if you created them before adding it to the prototype:

```
function Cat() {}

var c = new Cat();

Cat.prototype.test = function() {
    alert('test');
};

c.test(); // alerts 'test'
```

Answer (score 0):

> Moreover, what is the correct approach for querying the properties of an Object's prototype?

```
var myProto = Object.getPrototypeOf(someObject);
var names = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(myProto);
names.forEach(function (name) {
  value = myProto[name];
  ...
});
```

> Or does this happen only when I explicitly set Cat.prototype.eyes = brown as an example?

Yes, properties on the `[[Prototype]]` of an object are only set when you set them manually.

But since every "instance" of a prototype has a live pointer to the prototype object, these changes will reflect after the object has been created.

> store the properties of the constructor that will be inherited by all instances of cat- is this wrong?

We don't store properties of objects on the prototype. We store properties (mainly methods) that we want to share among all instances of a prototype/constructor.